# XcodeCloud build fails with "The ci_pre_xcodebuild.sh is executable but exited with 2 exit code."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

XcodeCloud build fails with following error -
The ci_pre_xcodebuild.sh is executable but exited with 2 exit code. Make sure a valid shebang line is specified if the file is a script and that the interpreter specified in the shebang line is supported on Xcode Cloud.

This is my script -

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ $CI_XCODEBUILD_ACTION = 'build' ]]; then
    brew install swiftlint
    cd ..
    swiftlint --strict
fi
```

Please let me know how can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have violations in your swift code and that's how `swiftlint` is telling you.  It should be outputting those violations to the console so you can see what they are.

Also `cd ..` is weak; use something like `cd $PROJECT_DIR` instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $CI_XCODEBUILD_ACTION = 'build' ]]; then
    which swiftlint >/dev/null || brew install swiftlint
    (cd $PROJECT_DIR; swiftlint --strict)
fi
```

Also you should be running `swiftlint` in a pre-commit hook so such errors are can be fixed before they reach your CI.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did in fact have swiftlint violations, build succeeded after resolving them.